# Mail uploaded Video

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working in an application  where I have to mail the captured video. I am not getting any solution.

Is it possible to do with share kit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the tutorial http://omnomrobot.com/tutorials/sourcetutorials/mfmailcompose/

In that tutorial replace  line 28 and 30 with

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData datawithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle MainBundle]pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];


[mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"video.mp4"];
```

change the format of video to appropriate format.